# valgrind error in ioctl() call, while sending an i2c message

Tags: c, valgrind, ioctl, initialization

valgrind is giving me the following error on the ioctl() line:
I am not sure how I could avert such an error.

> ==2764== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
>   ==2764==
>   ==2764== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
>   ==2764== **Syscall param ioctl(I2C_RDWR).msgs points to uninitialised byte(s)**
>   ==2764==    at 0x4E08EFEC: ioctl (syscall-template.S:81)
>   ==2764==    by 0x871F: imxSend_i2cMsg (imx6qi2c_wrapper.c:54)
>   ==2764==    by 0x87CB: imxSend_i2cByte (imx6qi2c_wrapper.c:84)
>   ==2764==    by 0x86D3: main (imx6qi2c_test.c:30)
>   ==2764==  Address 0x7db99b82 is on thread 1's stack
>   ==2764==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
>   ==2764==    at 0x875C: imxSend_i2cByte (imx6qi2c_wrapper.c:66)

the code in imx6qi2c_wrapper.c is the following:

```
int imxSend_i2cMsg(const int i2c_fd,
                   struct i2c_msg *i2cMsgArray,         
                   const unsigned int arraySize){
    int ret=0;
    struct i2c_rdwr_ioctl_data ioctl_pack;

    ioctl_pack.nmsgs=arraySize;
    ioctl_pack.msgs=i2cMsgArray;

    ret=ioctl(i2c_fd,I2C_RDWR,&ioctl_pack);

    return ret;
}
```

and "i2cMsgArray" is declared in annother function locally.

```
int imxSend_i2cByte(const int i2c_fd,
                      const unsigned char i2cAddress,
                      const unsigned char devRegister,
                      const unsigned char value){
    struct i2c_msg i2cmsg[I2CMSGS_TOTAL_WR];
    int ret=0,i=0;

    for (i=0;i<I2CMSGS_TOTAL_WR;i++){
        i2cmsg[i].buf=malloc(2*sizeof(char));
    } 

    i2cmsg[0].addr=i2cAddress;
    i2cmsg[0].flags=I2C_M_WR;
    i2cmsg[0].len=2;
    i2cmsg[0].buf[0]=devRegister;
    i2cmsg[0].buf[1]=value;

    ret=imxSend_i2cMsg(i2c_fd,&i2cmsg[0],I2CMSGS_TOTAL_WR);
    if (ret<0){
        printf("i2cmsg failed.errno is %d, %s\n",errno,strerror(errno));
    } 

    for (i=0;i<I2CMSGS_TOTAL_WR;i++){
        free(i2cmsg[i].buf);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

where is the uninitialized byte?

Comment: Isn't all memory for `i2cmsg[1]..i2cmsg[I2CMSGS_TOTAL_WR-1]` uninitialised?  You initialise `i2cmsg[0]` but not any subsequent elements.

Comment: `memset` to 0 on `i2cmsg` will solve your problem.

Comment: @Dayalrai You should make an answer out of your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok just for completion I copy here the answer given as a comment (but was never posted as an answer by the user who knew the answer).

```
memset to 0 on i2cmsg will solve your problem
```